# Better way for constant expressions in functions than storing as global variables?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, simplifying-expressions, variable

For example, I wrote a function like this:

```
inversions[list_] := Complement[
  Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5}, {2}],
  Subsets[list, {2}]
  ]
```

But as you see, every time I call `inversions[list]`, the large constant expression `Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5}, {2}]` is re-computed, which should've been avoided. Of course, I can achieve this by storing it as a global variable, like:

```
SUBSETS = Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5}, {2}];
inversions[list_] := Complement[
  SUBSETS,
  Subsets[list, {2}]
  ]
```

But this variable `SUBSETS` is used for only the function `inversions`, and thus should've been bound to this function, instead of dangling in the global scope like this. How can I do better to avoid the scope pollution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `With`. It will inject the pre-calculated value of the larger `Subsets` expression in your definition, but without “messing up” the readability of your code:

```
ClearAll[inversions]
With[
 {SUBSETS = Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5}, {2}]},
 inversions[list_] := Complement[SUBSETS,Subsets[list, {2}]]
]
```

You can check that downvalues (i.e. the definition) of `inversions` includes the pre-calculated expression using `?inversions`.

`SUBSETS` is treated like a macro in this context and it is never created as a symbol or given a definition, so it won’t “leak”.

Comment: Wow! I've never thought of putting a global definition inside a `With`. That should solve the problem. :-)

Answer (score 2):

> But this variable SUBSETS is used for only the function inversions,
> and thus should've been bound to this function, instead of dangling in
> the global scope like this

You could put the stuff inside some new context? From clean Kernel

```
Begin["myStuff`"]
SUBSETS = Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 7, 6, 5}, {2}];
inversions[list_] := Complement[SUBSETS, Subsets[list, {2}]];
End[]
```

And now no one can access it by accident. It is not in `Global` context any more.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To access anything in there, must use `myStuff` to see it.

```
 myStuff`inversions[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: By this we avoid polluting one context by polluting another, and it's more cumbersome to invoke the function.

Comment: @SneezeFor16Min it is an option. You do not have to use it. In Mathematica, there are 10 different ways to do the same thing. You choose which you like.,